# I have 2 errors compiling my java Lottery program using arrays

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LotteryGame{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int NUM_DIGITS = 6;

    int[] userDigits = new int[NUM_DIGITS];
    int[] lotteryNumbers = new int[NUM_DIGITS];
    int sameNum;

    generateNumbers(lotteryNumbers);
    getUserData(userDigits);
    sameNum = compareArrays(lotteryNumbers, userDigits);

    System.out.println("Winning numbers: " + lotteryNumbers[0] + " "
            + lotteryNumbers[1] + " " + lotteryNumbers[2] + " "
            + lotteryNumbers[3] + " " + lotteryNumbers[4] + " " + lotteryNumbers[5] + " ");

    System.out.println("Your numbers:  " + userDigits[0] + " "
            + userDigits[1] + " " + userDigits[2] + " " + userDigits[3]
            + " " + userDigits[4] + " " + userDigits[5] +" ");
    System.out.println("Number of matching digits: " + sameNum);

    if (sameNum == 6) {
        System.out.println("First prize!!!");
    }

    if (sameNum == 5) {
        System.out.println("Second prize!!!");
    }
    if (sameNum == 0) {
        System.out.println("No matching numbers, you lost.");
    }

}

public static void generateNumbers(int[] lotteryNumbers) {

    Random randNum = new Random();

    lotteryNumbers[0] = randNum.nextInt(59);
    lotteryNumbers[1] = randNum.nextInt(59);
    lotteryNumbers[2] = randNum.nextInt(59);
    lotteryNumbers[3] = randNum.nextInt(59);
    lotteryNumbers[4] = randNum.nextInt(59);
    lotteryNumbers[5] = randNum.nextInt(59);

    return lotteryNumbers[5];
}

public static void getUserData(int[] userDigits) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter first digit: ");
    userDigits[0] = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter second digit: ");
    userDigits[1] = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter third digit: ");
    userDigits[2] = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter fourth digit: ");
    userDigits[3] = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter fifth digit: ");
    userDigits[4] = keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter sixth digit: ");
    userDigits[5] = keyboard.nextInt();



    return userDigits[5];
}

public static int compareArrays(int[] userDigits, int[] lotteryNumbers) {
    int sameNum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
            if (lotteryNumbers[i] == userDigits[x]) {
                sameNum++;
            }
        }
    }
    return sameNum;
}

}
```

When I compile I get the following errors-

```
   LotteryGame.java:51: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
       return lotteryNumbers[5];
                         ^
   LotteryGame.java:72: error: incompatible types: unexpected return value
    return userDigits[5];
                     ^
      2 errors
```

Can any of you help me with these compilation errors? I'm trying to get this to work. The user is supposed to input 6 numbers, and the program is supposed to pick randomly 6 numbers. Using these numbers, the program will compare the numbers with echoed input.

Comment: `void` methods don't return anything. You need to specify what the methods are actually returning

Answer (score 0):

`generateNumbers` and `getUserData` are `void` functions, meaning they don't return anything, so you can't return anything from them.

You probably want to declare them as functions returning `int` instead:

```
public static int generateNumbers(int[] lotteryNumbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Univerio is correct in answering your original question.

Looking at your test code you might consider removing the return statement on those two functions since you are just populating both arrays.